# How do I access my viewController from my appDelegate? (Swift)

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, declaration, appdelegate

I am in my AppDelegate and I need to refresh the webview placed in my ViewController.

So I've googled how to call a method/variable from appDelegate and I found this:

```
MyViewController* mainController = (MyViewController*)  
self.window.rootViewController
```

And it looks like it works, but I'm working in Swift and I'm kinda of a noob trying to translate this without any luck.. this is my result but I can't manage to make it work..

```
ViewController vc = (ViewController) 
self.window?.rootViewController
```

What am I doing wrong?
How can I access to something in my viewcontroller from my appDelegate?

Thank you very much and have a nice day

Comment: Why does your app delegate need to do this? It doesn't sound like the app delegate's job.

Comment: a) You are declaring your `vc` variable incorrectly - that isn't how you declare a variable with a type in Swift. b) you are casting `self.window?.rootViewController` to `ViewController` which is incorrect, and also the wrong type. To be honest, you really need to spend more time reading the Swift introductory references rather that asking for direct code translations on SO. These are very basic concepts.

Comment: Use `NSNotifications` for this kind of things.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
let viewController = self.window.rootViewController as UIViewController
```